# etoolbox: trouble with boolean expressions

Tags: etoolbox

I'm new at making macros and am in the process of building a package to produce course outlines.  I want the user to input room/day/time information as below (where everything has been simplified to just using the room)

```
\newcounter{RoomCount}
\NewDocumentCommand\Room{R(){TBA}}{%
    \stepcounter{RoomCount}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname Room\theRoomCount\endcsname{#1}%
}
```

At this point I would like to feed this information into a tabular environment to format the room/day/time information.  To do so, I would like a macro that spits out 1 row for each room/day/time combination that has been input.  This macro would then be executed in a tabular environment to build the table.

```
\NewDocumentCommand\buildrows{}{%
\newbool{myBool}%
\booltrue{myBool}%
\newcounter{rownum}%
\whileboolexpr{myBool}{%
    \stepcounter{rownum}%
    \ifcsdef{Room\therownum}%
    {\csname Room\therownum\endcsname\\}%
    {\boolfalse{myBool}}%
}%
}
```

The intention of the loop is: check whether the user has input a second room, if so, then write a row for tabular, if not, then set myBool to false so that the loop exits.  The following, however, produces many "package etoolbox error: invalid boolean expression" errors

```
\begin{document}
\Room(C244)

\begin{tabular}{l}
  \buildrows{}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

At this point I don't have enough "tools in my toolbox" to figure out what I'm doing wrong so any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!
ps.  The full example would be:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{RoomCount}
\NewDocumentCommand\Room{+R(){TBA}}{%
\stepcounter{RoomCount}%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname Room\theRoomCount\endcsname{#1}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand\buildrows{}{%
\newbool{myBool}%
\booltrue{myBool}%
\newcounter{rownum}%
\whileboolexpr{myBool}{%
    \stepcounter{rownum}%
    \ifcsdef{Room\therownum}%
    {\csname Room\therownum\endcsname}%
    {\boolfalse{myBool}}%
}%
}

\begin{document}
\Room(C244)

\begin{tabular}{l}
\buildrows{}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some small mistakes you have done:

- If you set `\newbool{myBool}` and `\newcounter{rownum}` inside the definition of the command `\buildrows`, the commands will be defined every time you call the command `\buildrows`. So the definition must be done before.
- The command `\whileboolexpr` doesn't accept a single bool. The first argument of `whileboolexpr` evaluates the first argument. This is described in [section 3.6.5 of the documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox).
- This is really a tip: Instead of using `\expandafter` you can use the command `\csdef` provided by `etoolbox`.

Here a complete MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{RoomCount}
\NewDocumentCommand\Room{+R(){TBA}}{%
 \stepcounter{RoomCount}%
 \csdef{Room\theRoomCount}{#1}%
}
\newbool{myBool}%
\newcounter{rownum}%
\setcounter{rownum}{0}
\NewDocumentCommand\buildrows{}{%
 \booltrue{myBool}%
 \whileboolexpr{ bool {myBool} }{%
    \stepcounter{rownum}%
    \ifcsdef{Room\therownum}%
    {\csname Room\therownum\endcsname}%
    {\boolfalse{myBool}}%
 }%
}

\begin{document}
\Room(C244)

\Room(C247)

\begin{tabular}{l}
\buildrows{}
\end{tabular}

\buildrows{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt answer Marco.  Thank you for the tips, and the answer to my problem...since it was tucked down a little lower, I had missed that part of the documentation!  In editing my original example I missed an important part which now seems to be an issue.  I think I will have to make another question :(